# How do I make a jumping animation in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

So I'm making this Unity2D game and I'm trying to implement a jumping animation, it has 5 states(launching, rising, apex, falling, landing).
How should I set up the transitions between these states?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Go onto Youtube and search "How to make an animation in Unity2D". This place is for help and advice, not for us to do your work for you :) Good luck! If something goes wrong and you've tried to fix it, then come here and we can try and help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Blend tree](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlendTree-1DBlending.html). There's also plenty of tutorials on youtube/unity to show exactly how to use.